# How do I get Safari 15 to load multiple tabs in the background?

Tags: safari, bookmarks, tabs

I have a bookmarks folder that is set up to open all the bookmarks with a single click. (I think this is Automatically Replace Tabs, or <kbd>⌘-Click</kbd> on the folder).

Before Safari 15 all of the tabs would load in the background which I found to be convenient. Beginning with Safari 15, tabs only start loading when you open the tab. This is annoying.

For example, this morning I opened all the bookmarks. I looked at a few. Before checking the rest I made some coffee and took a walk around the neighborhood with my wife. When I got back, a half hour later, the tabs I hadn’t looked at yet still hadn’t loaded.

Is there any way to get back to the feature of having the tabs load in the background?